# How to remove all tags from Tk Text() object

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have a text object that has some tags in it. It isn't defined what the text is because it is editable. I am trying to remove all tags from that `Text()` object. The object is called `text`.

I tried using a for loop, but it isn't working the way I want it to. If it helps, I am using Python 3.2.

I also have a dictionary of what the tags are. Here is the link:

http://pastebin.com/MTwM0yrQ

Syntax:

```
'word/tagName':'color(don't mess with this)',...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
for tag in text.tag_names():
    text.tag_delete(tag)
```

I haven't actually tested this, but if I understand the docs correctly, it ought to work.

Comment: can you use `tag_remove`?

Comment: @programfast: `tag_remove` removes the tag from the text but leaves the definition of the tag alone. `tag_delete` removes the tag from the text and also removes the definition of the tag.

Comment: The `sel` tag will remain after this; it's managed by the `text` itself and represents the current selected text. The `tag_remove` needs extra arguments as it removes the tag from a character or range of characters.